# SQL Server Profiler is available for SQL Server 2008 Dev Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, profiler

I just upgrade from SQL Server 2008 Express with advance services to Dev Edition. I wonder whether SQL Profiler is available for the Dev Edition?

Please let me know how to access that if it is present.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is available in the installer for development edition. Without firing it up, I'm not sure if the installer has changed between 2008 and 2008R2 but in 2008 there are two options for installing client tools.

- Management Tools (Basic) which installs SSMS, SQLCMD and Powershell support
- Management Tools (Complete) adds Profiler, Database Tuning Advisor, Integration Services, Reporting Services.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to uninstall Management Studio Express in order to have the option to install Management Tools from Dev edition. Pretty sure they can't co-exist and Management Tools might be greyed out in the installer if SSMSE is already present.